# KIK Card - sending message directly

Tags: ios, heroku, kik

I'm building new KIK Card and i would like to create button which will send messages to 5 people selected from kik.pickUsers Is there any command that allow me to send messages directly, without pressing button "send"? This is my code:

```
cards.kik.pickUsers({
    minResults: 5, // number >= 5
    maxResults: 99 // number < 99
}, function (users) {
    if (!users) {
        return;
    }



    users.forEach(function (user) {
        cards.kik.send(user.username, {
            title: 'Message',
            text: 'Text!!!'
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Messages cannot be sent directly without user consent (via pressing the "send" button) - this is a tactic to avoid apps spamming content messages on behalf of the user.

Regarding sending to multiple people, as of this writing you can only send a message to a group if the conversation already exists in Kik.

Iterating over the array of users returned from the picker and trying to use `kik.send()` for each will only work for the first user in the array.

The Pop app on Kik has a good implementation to overcome this for inviting friends to use the app. This may or may not be relevant depending on what you are developing.